# Get filesize over URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, download, volume, filesize

In PHP, there is a function named

```
GetRealVolume(filesize("FILEPATH"));
```

I seacrh one for javascript.
Can i get the Filesize from a Filepath?

I want make a link like that:

```
<a href="FILEPATH">Klick for Download [FILESIZE]</a>
```

Comment: Are Files from same domain or different domain?

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 allows you to do stuff like this through the File interface: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file

so you can do:

```
fileEntry.getMetadata(function(metadata){console.log(metadata.size)})
```

The downside is that this would only work on your application sandbox, it is not that easy to access the general file system for security reasons, although you could give this atry: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/460516-check-file-size-javascript.

Comment: I tried this:

`$.get("1234/docs/new/file.pdf", function(data){
    console.log(data.size);
  });`
but it doesn't work